# Использовать очень долгую сессию в php

Tags: php, сессия

Как можно увеличить срок жизни сессии если пользователь нажал "запомнить меня". Или никак и нужно использовать куки?

Comment: разве что заносить значение в `БД` при нажатии кнопки `запомнить меня`, и наоборот при выходе. Но это моя бредовая идея)

Comment: Да, как-то не очень практично. Но спасибо за внимание.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сессии для этого использовать нельзя.

Надо использовать куки. Пишем в куку и в БД одно и то же уникальное значение, при заходе пользователя читаем куку и если такая находится в БД - авторизуем пользователя.

Comment: Где-то вроде читал что можно продлить время жизни сессии и не использовать куки. Но видимо это только меняя настройки самого php.

Comment: @АлександрПушкин сессии удаляются после закрытия браузера, нужно использовать cookies. Человек правильно говорит.

Comment: @АлексейПересторонин, да, так и сделал.

Answer (score 0):

В php есть [настройки во время выполнения](http://php.net/manual/ru/session.configuration.php) отвечающие за время хранении сессии на сервере, вы можете установить очень большое значение, например 10 лет, это будет равносильно вечности) Но это будет касаться всех пользователей, для отдельных - только решение с кукой, в которой сгенерирован код для автологина, так называемый token, который вы сверяете со сгенерированным на сервере и если они совпадают  - то логините пользователя, всю сессию хранить необязательно, конечно если это не пропиворечит логике самого приложения.

```
session.cookie_lifetime
session.gc_maxlifetime
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо за инфу.

Comment: Что мне всегда нравилось в пользователях РНР - это безбрежность полета их фантазии.